# How to analyse GCP logs in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, google-cloud-platform

Is there some way we can move the logs generated in Google Cloud Platform console to elasticsearch for analysis?

I Googled and found the elasticsearch plugin but could not find how to actually export the logs.

Any pointers will help.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try reading the guide https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2 ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I read that guide and it talks about being able to export the logs to BigQuery, Cloud Storage or pubsub. I couldn't really understand how to use logstash to export logs from either of these source to elastic. Maybe I am missing something very obvious, but I am somewhat new to this yet.